# learning js with es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following simple code:

```
window.Foo = window.Foo || {};

((Foo) => {
  'use strict';

  Foo.select = Foo.select || {};

  Foo.select.init = (selector, options) => {
    ...
  };

  Foo.select.otherInit = () => {
    ...
  };

  $((e) => {
    Foo.select.init();
    Foo.select.otherInit();
  });

})(window.Foo);
```

As I am a js principiant I wonder a couple of things:

First the stupid one: instead of passing `Foo` can I access it by `this.Foo` inside the function? As I guess so, is it just kind of code style?

what does `(window.Foo)` in the last line mean? what's for?

Lastly, why using:

```
$((e) => {
  Foo.select.init();
  Foo.select.otherInit();
});
```

and not just:

```
Foo.select.init();
Foo.select.otherInit();
```

thank you!

Comment: This is namespace protection (wrapping all local variables inside a function). In ES6 can be done more elegantly using modularization.

Comment: To answer your last question: IIFE. So you are passing `window.Foo` as an argument.

Comment: re `$((e)` - learn jQuery basics

Comment: @Sulthan, please, could you elaborate or give me a resource about ES6 modularization used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First the stupid one: instead of passing Foo can I access it by
>   this.Foo inside the function? As I guess so, is it just kind of code
>   style?

Yes, you could access it directly through `this.Foo`, but only because the current function-scope is bound to the `window` Object (because you are using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) and because `Foo` is part of `window` (possibly due to the fact that it was just defined in the global scope).

If you were to try this in a function call inside another object, `this.Foo` would fail. I would not recommend doing this, unless you have a good reason to do it this way.

[Here can learn more about arrow functions and the `this` context.](http://blog.getify.com/arrow-this/)

> what does (window.Foo) in the last line mean? what's for?

Your whole construct (see below) is an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression): Immediately-invoked function expression. You are using an arrow function, so this binds the context as well (see point above).

The last part, `(window.Foo)`, means that you invoke the function you called with the argument `window.Foo`,  which is then available as `Foo` within your function.

```
((Foo) => {
    ...
})(window.Foo);
```

> Lastly, why using:
>
> $((e) => {   Foo.select.init();   Foo.select.otherInit(); });
>
> and not just:
>
> Foo.select.init(); Foo.select.otherInit();

This is a [jQuery function call, which is executed once the DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3). The function within `$(...)` is called, once the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired.

If this were not present, the code could be executed before the DOM is ready (thus possibly not finding the DOM elements referenced in those functions). This depends on where you place your javascript code though (if you place it right before `</body>` you should be safe).